# Como arreglar el error funcion not defined

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
function comprobarCondicion(opcion) {
      this.value = opcion;

      if (opcion == '164.132.203.28:455') {

      }
}
```

si la coloco en **index.html** , me funciona y si la coloco en mi *.js* principal no funciona , por si acaso si estoy llamando al *js* desde el index.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mt6.js"></script>
```

y la llamo en un `onchange` a la funcion.

```
onchange="comprobarCondicion(this.value)"
```

Bueno en fin, el error es que la funcion me aparece como no definida si la coloco en mi *.js* y si la coloco en el **index.html** va todo bien.

Comment: la primera línea dentro del function no es necesaria

Comment: y eso soluciona algo ?

Comment: @EduardoCampos ya probaste con `window.onload = function() {`

Comment: la ruta al archivo esta bien `js/mt6.js` prueba con `/js/mt6.js`

Comment: @x-rw como funciona eso? perdon mi ignorancia.

Comment: Alguien podria ayudarme?

Comment: En el head !!!!

Comment: Al parecer has puesto mal la ruta del archivo externo. Esto lo puedes saber si abres la consola y miras si tienes algún error 404 que significa "Nor found".

Comment: esta todo correcto , la web depende de ese archivo y si no estuviera ese archivo no funcionaria , pruebalo en ogar.pw

Comment: nadie puede ayudarme

Comment: Porque la he quitado , mira la agregare ahora y veras

Comment: observa ahora..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu error se debe a que tienes la función dentro de una IIFE (*Immediately invoked function expression*):

```
// IIFE
(function () {
  ...
  // no es visible fuera
  function comprobarCondicion (value) {
    ...
  }
})();
```

Este tipo de funciones se ejecutan immediatamente una vez que son leídas. Dado que `comprobarCondicion` está dentro de la IIE, **no es visible** fuera de ésta, por ende, cuando en la etapa de parseo se trata de encontrar a `comprobarCondicion` en el scope de `window`, falla, ya que, obviamente, no está allí.

Debes sacar la función y ponerla fuera de la IIFE:

```
(function () {
  ...
})();

function comprobarCondicion (value) {
  ...
}
```

> ¿Si coloco la función fuera no podre usar las variables que estan dentro?

No, no podrás, porque `var` tiene un ámbito de función que es, en este caso, la IIFE. Algo mejor que puedes hacer es lo siguiente: dentro de la IIFE, añadir el listener para `change` al elemento deseado.

```
(function () {
  var algo = 'algo';
  var otraCosa = 'otraCosa';
  var otraMas = 'otra Mas');

  ...

  // cambia aquí por el id de tu elemento
  $('#selectCondicion').on('change', function (e) {
    if($(this).val() === '164.132.203.28:455') {
      // hacer algo
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia Guz , pero exactamente en donde la coloco entonces?

Comment: Así como te lo indico en el último código que he puesto. Debajo de `(function() { })();` (al final del fichero, vamos).

Comment: Oh , gracias me ha servido mucho :D

Comment: pero una cosa , si lo coloco fuera no podre usar las variables que estan dentro ?

Comment: Actualizaré mi respuesta con tu duda.

Comment: Ya está. Revisa lo último que puse.

Comment: Oh oh , espera espera , he borrado del onchange la llamada de la funcion y me ha quedado asi:                                                                                         $('#gamemode').on('change', function (e) {
    if($(this).val() === '164.132.203.28:455') {
      // hacer algo
    }
  });

Comment: <select id="gamemode" class="form-control" onchange="setserver($(this).val());">

Comment: y la funcion que me diste dentro del IIFEE , pero no me ha funcionado , lol soy muy novato :(

Comment: Quita el onchage del select.

Comment: esque esa funcion setserver , cumple otra funcion , se me complica

Comment: Pero no te compliques. dentro de la función luego de 'change', llama a `setServer`. Es lo mismo que si hicieses `onchange="setServer(this.value)`.

Comment: Disculpa mi novatez , pero estoy aprendiendo js hace muy poco y bueno no entiendo como llamar a la funcion aca , ando muy basico en js , he hecho esto y nose porque no pasa nada ahora

Comment: $('#gamemode').on('change', function (e) {
  setserver(this.val);
    if($(this).val() == '164.132.203.28:455') {
      console.log('12');
    }
  });

Comment: Es correcto, pero en lugar de `setserver(this.val);` usa `setserver($(this).val());`. Recuerda que estás usando jQuery.

Comment: ya lo puse como me dijiste miralo tu mismo aca http://ogar.pw/js/mt6.js , alfinal del todo, y no me funciona :c

Comment: Tu código es incorrecto. La manera correcta es como te muestro [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/9pbpj2cb/).

Comment: oh , he agregado esto : $('#gamemode').on('change', function () {
   setserver($(this).val());
  }); y tampoco me ha funcionado de todas maneras gracias no quiero molestarte mas con mi novatez

Comment: oh , me funciono porque lo puse en document.ready